# Progressively "revealing" a 3d object in Three.js -- Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to create an animated 3d line chart in three.js.  Trick is I want it to "reveal" from left to right, kind of like this example from CNBC... http://youtu.be/ds7zhCqlrqk?t=12s

I looked into how I might hide/mask/clip part the chart and then animate the mask to reveal, but that doesn't seem possible as far as I can tell.

So I resorted to completely recreating the chart's geometry and mesh with each frame, adding a bit more to the chart each time.  Works well enough and I'm well within the frame rate I need to hit, but it seems rather brute force and I'm wondering if there's an easier way that I'm not aware of.

Here's a jsFiddle of what I have now.  http://jsfiddle.net/qzpC6/9/
And here's the function that rebuilds the chart geometry and mesh with each frame...

```
function incrementChart() {
    if (currentPoint == points.length - 1) {
        return;
    }

    var then = new Date().getTime();
    currentPoint++;
    var extent = startX;
    var vectors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= currentPoint; i++) {
        vectors.push(new THREE.Vector2(extent, 50 * points[i]));
        extent += spacing;
    }
    console.log(vectors);
    vectors.push(new THREE.Vector2(extent - spacing, -50));
    vectors.push(new THREE.Vector2(startX, -50));
    vectors.push(new THREE.Vector2(startX, 50 * points[0]));

    var newShape = new THREE.Shape(vectors);
    var newGeometry = newShape.extrude(extrudeSettings);
    var newShapeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(newShape.extrude(extrudeSettings), material);

    parent.remove(shapeMesh);
    shapeMesh = newShapeMesh;
    parent.add(shapeMesh);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(now - then);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How familiar are you with shaders? You could use a ShaderMaterial and progressively discard fragments based on their gl_FragCoord.x

Comment: I eventually figured this out, but never got around to learning enough glsl to do it.  And i think it might still have a problem with how to "seal off" the right end of the geometry.  I also considered doing a separate render pass and using the "scissor" parameter on the renderer to just clip off the part i don't want to see.  Ultimately just did it in a different style.